# Given the sum of elements of all $2^n$ subsets of a multiset with $n$ elements, find the elements of the multiset.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

By multiset, I mean a set which can have repeated elements.

I'm looking for an algorithm for this problem.

Edit: The elements of the given multiset are all >= 0.

Edit2: Example: Given {0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7}, the output should be {1, 3, 3}

Comment: Hint: How many times does each particular element appear in the sum over all the sub(multi)sets?

Comment: I would say each element contributes to 2^(N-1) sums. I'll think on this some more, I did think over this problem quite a bit before taking the stackexchange leap :D.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question.  Perhaps you could give an example of what you know and what you want to deduce.  For example, do you start with an overall sum of $28$ with the multiset possibly being three terms with a sum of $7$? Or do you start with sums of $0,1,3,3,4,4,6,7$ and you are supposed to deduce the original multiset was $\{1,3,3\}$?

Comment: The second one. I start with {0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7} and have to find {1, 3, 3}

Comment: If they're all known to be nonnegative, you can easily find the smallest element, and then probably recurse (perhaps with some branching to test possibilities).

Comment: @GregMartin Could you explain your method in a bit more detail if possible? I know I can find the first two elements as the second smallest and third smallest in the given list.

Comment: If the multiset of subsums is $0\le s_1\le s_2\le\cdots$, then the smallest element in the output is $s_1$. The second smallest is automatically $s_2$, unless $s_2=2s_1$, in which case the second smallest could be either $s_1$ or $2s_1$. So branch on both possibilities and keep going....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the original set, and $S$ be the set of sums.

Consider the following process:

Let $A_0 = \{\}$, and let $S_0 = S \setminus \{0\}$.

At each subsequent step, let $A_{i + 1} = A_{i} \cup \min S_i$, and let $S_{i + 1} = S \setminus P_{i + 1}$, where $P_i$ is the multiset of sums of the power set of $A_i$.

Note that at each step, $\min S_i$ must be in $A$, as it is not generated as the sum of smaller elements of $A$.

Thus, $A_n = A$.

**Edit:** Here's a Python implementation that runs in $O(n \cdot 2^n)$ time.

```
def log_set(power_set_sums):
    s = power_set_sums[:]
    heapq.heapify(s)

    a = []
    p = [0]

    to_delete = [0]

    while s:
        x = heapq.heappop(s)
        if to_delete and to_delete[0] == x:
            heapq.heappop(to_delete)
        else:
            a.append(x)
            for i, y in enumerate(p[:]):
                p.append(x + y)
                if i != 0:
                    heapq.heappush(to_delete, x + y)

    return a
```

Comment: You could implement this algorithm (with some optimization) in $O(n \cdot 2^n)$.  You're going to need to look at every element of $S$ at least once to find the minimum, so that puts it at $\Omega(2^n)$.  I'd be surprised if you can get rid of that factor of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implementation of the algorithm of Mnemonic

- the first item is taken and negated
- at each iteration, the 1st positive item is taken. Then, it is added to all the previous negated items to flags the new sums by negating them.

We may take the 1st item because it is , at this step , the lowest one which is not a sum of the previous values. It cannot no more be a sum of the following values, then it is a root value.

To run the script , copy paste it in Scratchpad , the firefox tool or something similar and do a Ctrl L. The last variable modified is output.

```
function devloop(n,sett)
{
    var ret = [0] ;
    for( var i = 0 ; i < sett.length ; i ++ )
    {
        lret = ret.length ;
        for( var j = 0 ; j < lret ; j ++ )
        {
            ret.push( ret[j]+sett[i] ) ;
        }
    }

    return ret.sort(function(a, b){return a-b}) ;
}
function remsum(ords,newd,start)
{
    var i , j , val ;
// heavy and somehow brute ! must record a state with more than 2 values
    var ords2 = []; 
    for( i = 0 ; i < ords.length ; i++ )
    {
        ords2[i]  = ords[i]; 
        if( ords[i] <= 0 )
        {
            ords2.push(ords[i]); 
        }
    }

    for( j = 0 ;  j < ords2.length ; j++ )
    {
        val = newd-ords2[j] ;
        for( i = start ;  i < ords.length  ; i++ )
        {
            if( ords[i] == val )
            {
                ords[i] = -ords[i] ;
                start = i + 1 ;
                break ;
            }
        }
    }
    return  ords ;
}


function main(ordsum,n)
{
    var lordsum = ordsum.length , lordsum2 = lordsum/2 , sett=[ ordsum[1] ] , ok = false , found = 1 ,i ;
    // remove 1 time ordsum[1]
    ordsum[ 1 ] = -ordsum[ 1 ] ;

    for( i = 2 ;  found < n && i <= lordsum ; i ++)
    {
        if( ordsum[i] > 0 )
        {
            sett.push( ordsum[i] ) ;
            ordsum = remsum(ordsum,ordsum[i],i) ;
            found ++ ;
        }
    }
    return sett;
}
//  var ordsumE = [0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7] , nE = 3 ;

// argum of the test

var res="", trvE , nE ;

var trvEListe = [
// 1st test
        [1,2,3,6,12,14,26] ,

// 2nd test
        [1,2,3,6,9,11,12,14,26] ,

// 3rd test
        [1,2,2,6,8,10,10,12,13,14,26] ,

// 4th test
        [1,1,2,2,2,6,8,10,10,10,13,14,126]
        ] ;

for( var nn = 0 ; nn < 4 ; nn ++ )
{
    trvE = trvEListe[nn] ;
    nE = trvE.length ;

// res = the output
    res += ("\n\nthe list to find :\n\t"+trvE.join(",")+"\n") ;
// build the ordered sums
    var ordsumE = devloop( nE,trvE ) ;
    res += ("the 2^n sums for the function input:\n\t"+ ordsumE.join(",").substr(0,40)+"...\n") ;

// and try to find trvE
    res += ( "return :\n\t"+main(ordsumE,nE).join(",")+"\n" ) ;
}
res = res + "\n" ;
```

ouput

```
the list to find :
    1,2,3,6,12,14,26
the 2^n sums for the function input: 
    0,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,11,12,12,13...
return :
    1,2,3,6,12,14,26


the list to find :
    1,2,3,6,9,11,12,14,26
the 2^n sums for the function input:
    0,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,10,11,12,9,10,...
return :
    1,2,3,6,9,11,12,14,26


the list to find :
    1,2,2,6,8,10,10,12,13,14,26
the 2^n sums for the function input: 
    0,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,9,10,11,8,9,10...
return :
    1,2,2,6,8,10,10,12,13,14,26


the list to find :
    1,1,2,2,2,6,8,10,10,10,13,14,126
the 2^n sums for the function input: 
    0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,2,3,3,4,...
return :
    1,1,2,2,2,6,8,10,10,10,13,14,126
```

Comment: What is the complexity of this approach?

Comment: Oh wait Mnemonic is the previous answerer... So I take it the complexity is O(n * 2^n)?